# SQL Server query to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

Please help me to convert this SQL Server Query to a Postgres query. I am using Postgresql 9.3.I am not able to get the desired output in postgres

```
If object_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp') is not NULL
    Drop table #tmp;

create table #tmp
(
variable_int_col int,
timestamp_int_col int,
value_col int
)

insert into #tmp values
(8,1449486435,25),
(8,1449486436,26),
(9,1449486435,40),
(9,1449486436,44),
(9,1449486440,52)

select * from #tmp

Declare @sql varchar(max);
Declare @sql2 varchar(max);

set @sql= STUFF((select distinct ','+ QUOTENAME(variable_int_col) from #tmp FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'');
set @sql2= STUFF((select distinct ','+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(variable_int_col) + ',0)' + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('variable_' + cast(variable_int_col as varchar) + '_value') from #tmp FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'');

set @sql='select timestamp_int_col,' + @sql2 + ' from #tmp t  
               PIVOT (SUM(value_col) FOR variable_int_col IN ('+@sql+')) p';
-- print @sql

If object_ID(N'dbo.newTable') is not NULL
    Drop table newTable;

set @sql='select * into newTable from (' + @sql + ') s';

exec(@sql);

select * from newTable;
```

I have tried But failed to convert this line

```
set @sql='select timestamp_int_col,' + @sql2 + ' from #tmp t  
                   PIVOT (SUM(value_col) FOR variable_int_col IN ('+@sql+')) p';
```

Please Help

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuncname() RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
Declare 
v_sql text;
Declare 
v_sql2 text;
BEGIN
v_sql :=  STRING_AGG(Distinct(("VARIABLE"):: text), ',')   From "ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_A3";
v_sql2 := STRING_AGG(Distinct('COALESCE(' || ("VARIABLE"):: text || ',0) AS variable_' || ("VARIABLE"):: text) || '_value', ',')   From "ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_A3";

v_sql :='select TIMESTAMP_S,' || v_sql2 || ' from ARCHIEVE_EXPORT_DB_AR3 t  
               crosstab(SUM(VALUE) FOR VARIABLE IN (' || v_sql ||')) p';
               execute(v_sql);
END
$$;
SELECT somefuncname();

Comment: `If object_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp') is not NULL  Drop table #tmp;` would be `drop temporary table if exists tmp` (alternatively  `create temp table if not exists ...`)

Comment: It would be **much** easier if you described the underlying problem you are trying to solve rather than dumping a bunch of code. Each DBMS needs to be used differently. Translating code 1:1 from one system to another almost never makes sense. A different DBMS requires a different approach. Post your table definitions, some sample data and the expected output based on that data, then maybe someone can come up with a solution. Someone that knows Postgres well, might not even understand what that T-SQL code is doing.